# Please explain this probability function?

Tags: probability

let x be a random variable

flip a coin

if it's on heads x = 1

if it's on tails uniform throughout [0,1)

is there a name for this kind of probability? is it two random variables?

source:
https://youtu.be/RjPXfUT7Odo?t=4m35s

Comment: Explain what you have tried. Post a complete problem statement and delete the youtube link. No one is going to want to watch a video just to answer your question.

Comment: it's time stamped; it's like a 30s segment

Comment: It looks like a *mixture distribution* with a discrete component and a continuous component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your distribution is a *mixture* or *convex combination* of a point mass at 1 and the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  More precisely, a 50-50 mixture.